# Main content shifts when hover over nav link

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style `nav` link which on `hover` displays a text. But the `main` content also shifts as the `width` property of the link changes. The html and css so far is

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
p {
  margin: 0%;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.gap-1 {
  gap: 1rem;
}
.default {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
.default:hover {
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 1rem;
}
.default:hover svg {
  padding: 5px;
}
.default:hover span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="flex gap-1">
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li class="default">
                <svg
                  stroke="currentColor"
                  fill="currentColor"
                  stroke-width="0"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  height="1em"
                  width="1em"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                >
                  <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path>
                  <path
                    d="M4 10h3v7H4zM10.5 10h3v7h-3zM2 19h20v3H2zM17 10h3v7h-3zM12 1L2 6v2h20V6z"
                  ></path>
                </svg>
                <span class="hidden">Home</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          <main>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
            </p>
          </main>
        </div>
```

With this code when we hover over the `li` the hidden text is displayed also shifting the main content. What I'm trying to achieve is on hover the hidden text is displayed, like an overlay on top of the main without moving it. Any help suggestions would be beneficial.

Comment: One way of doing this is by using position:absolute on either one of the elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by adding `position: absolute` on the "main" tag item (preferably with a class or id).

Since it's inside a `<div>`, it will be easier to adjust the margin afterwards.

You could achieve the same result by giving `position: absolute` to the `<ul>` with a positive `z-index`value.

```css
ul {
  background: white; /* Added to make it more visible */
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
p {
  margin: 0%;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.gap-1 {
  gap: 1rem;
}
.default {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
.default:hover {
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 1rem;
}
.default:hover svg {
  padding: 5px;
}
.default:hover span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

/* Main tag changed to be under the ul */
main {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 50px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
 <div class="flex gap-1">
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li class="default">
                <svg
                  stroke="currentColor"
                  fill="currentColor"
                  stroke-width="0"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  height="1em"
                  width="1em"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                >
                  <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path>
                  <path
                    d="M4 10h3v7H4zM10.5 10h3v7h-3zM2 19h20v3H2zM17 10h3v7h-3zM12 1L2 6v2h20V6z"
                  ></path>
                </svg>
                <span class="hidden">Home</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          <main>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
            </p>
          </main>
        </div>
```